# How to coordinate sound and animation in Libgdx?

Tags: java, android, animation, audio, libgdx

I am trying to make an intro screen for an game which has 2 animations and 2 sound clips. I want it to play one after another (Animation 1 -> Sound 1(5 sec) -> Animation 2 -> Sound 2(2 sec) -> new Screen).I am using two listeners for animations

```
secondAnimation.setListener(new OnAnimationComplete() {
        @Override
        public void setNextScreen() {
            animation.startAnimation = true; }

    });

    animation.setListener(new OnAnimationComplete() {
        @Override
        public void setNextScreen() {
            game.setScreen(new JumbleGameScreen1(game, 2));
        }
    });
```

I can't use sound inside render() and when i'm using music it is affecting the animation. How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Why can't you a play a sound in render()?

Comment: It keeps on playing the starting part of the clip again and again, like if the first word of the clip is zorro, it will play 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzz'

Comment: Can we see the part of code where you actually play sounds ?

Comment: Sounds like you as rent wrapping it in some kind of if-clause so you are calling play() over and over continuously.

Comment: Add some static bool variable, "soundOneStarted" and set it initially to false. And then whey you have to start playing check on that variable first. If sound didn't start yet play it and change variable to true so sound would start only first time this is called.